# How to handle JSON null case in Swift 4 Codable while using Realm Database?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, codable

I am using Codable in Swift 4 along side with Realm Database for Swift.
The API I am using sends some fields as **null** which **Codable** could handle if that was mentioned as **optional**, that I know, now I can not do that because **@objc** annotation is mandatory in **RealmSwift 4** and being that those fields can not be optional and have to initialized with some value.If i try to do that it says

> Property can not be marked @objc because it's type can not be replaced
>   in Objective C

Below are some of the codable classes which are also realm object classes

```
class HUB: Object,Codable{

    @objc dynamic var hubId:String?
    @objc dynamic var lastKnownIp:String?
    @objc dynamic var lastKnownPort:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var nodes:[Node]?

}
class Node:Object,Codable {
    @objc dynamic var appStatus:Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var apps:[NodeApp]?
}
```

If any value among the above is null in JSON then **Codable** decoding fails giving error

> valueNotFound(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0),
>   CodingKeys(stringValue: "nodes", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue:
>   "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "appStatus",
>   intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Int value but found null
>   instead.", underlyingError: nil))

How can I solve it?

Comment: If a property can be `nil` you have to make it optional `var appStatus : Int?`. But consider to refactor the database side to store non-optional data.

Comment: I can make it optional but then realm complains that corresponding object-C replacement can not be found as it is annoted with objc. and objc is mandatory as of realmswift 3.7.6. I did not get your last part? How can I make do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Realm but I'm sure that an attribute can be declared not to be `null`. For the integer try `NSNumber?` rather than `Int?` if this doesn't work either you have to write a custom initializer to map the types.

Comment: JSONDecoder can be initialized with overriding init method with decoder. I got the container making concept with keys and non keys. But then we have to do it for every single field as we don't know beforehand which value is gonna be null. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: If you are responsible for the Realm database model you are supposed to know which values can be `null`. Avoid `null` values as much as possible.

Comment: did you solve your problem

Comment: @SharartiKAKI no. had to create separate classes for realm only

Comment: isnt there anyother choice

Comment: for now there is nothing we can do as it seems. tried everything but nothing was working.